# Best platform for complex SDPs with n and m around 5-15K?

Tags: constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, software-recommendation

I am looking to solve a class of SDPs with complex entries, with the semi-definite cone $S^n$, $n$ around 5000 to 15000. Also, $m$, the number of equality/inequality constraints is close to $n$.

I tried `SeDuMi` and `SDPT3` with `CVX`, but I quickly run out of memory for $n=1000, m=1000$ (I have about 50 GB available). Could you suggest other (free) SDP solvers that I could use?

I looked at the documentation for `SDPA`, and it claims to have much lower memory usage than the solvers mentioned above. In one of the cases, the memory use is claimed to be around 5% as `SDPT3`. The matrices in my problem aren't very sparse, but there are about 20% non-zeros.

Is `YALMIP` + `SDPA` is a good combination for my problem?

Please note that I have complex numbers involved, and I would like to avoid changing my formulation to convert everything into real, if possible.

Comment: Can you describe your objective function?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using SCS, either the direct or indirect solver.  SCS uses first-order methods, and hence may be able to solve larger problems than second-order solvers such as SDPT3, SeDuMi, MOSEK, etc.  On the downside, given that it is a first-order solver, it can be very slow - but very slow may be better than not at all.

Paper: [http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/scs.pdf](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/scs.pdf)

MATLAB code (need to make): https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs/tree/master/matlab

You can use SCS under YALMIP or under CVX 3.0 beta. Under CVX 3.0 beta, you can specify

```
cvx_solver scs
```

which will invoke the SCS direct solver.  To invoke the SCS indirect solver, also do

```
cvx_solver_settings('use_indirect',true);
```

Comment: In addition to SCS you also have the first-order solver SDPNAL, also interfaced in YALMIP.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into SCS solver as suggested. I am confused about the terminology in the related paper. In table 4, results are shown for 3 different sizes of problems. Could you clarify if the "number of variables" in that table corresponds to n^2 in the terminology I use above. If the desired semidefinite matrix is n×n, is the "number of varibles" as mentioned in SCS paper close to $n^2/2$ ?

Also, why does the paper only talk about case n<m ? My problem doesn't satisfy that criterion.

Comment: CVX and YALMIP will take care of getting your problem into a form the solver can handle, and with YALMIP, you have a dualize option.  I'm not sure this is correct, but perhaps your sparsity (0.2) times your n * m would be roughly comparable to the number of non-zeros in A. So m = n = 10000 would correspond to 2e7 non-zeros.  However, I'm not sure that is correct and will reflect what CVX or YALMIP will pass to the solver. I'm sure Johan could give a more definitive answer, which perhaps depends on the entirety of your problem, which you have not shown.

Comment: It all depends on the problem formulation, and how you interpret it. If you have one semidefinite $n\times n$ variable $X$ with a constrained trace, it would be wrong to say $n^2/2$ variables as that really doesn't align well with the computational complexity theory. It is a problem living in the n-dimensional primal semidefinite cone with 1 equality, i.e., if interpreted in the dual cone, it is a problem with $1$ variable, i.e., pretty simple.